# Possible timing issue with BOF and EOF properties in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have created a test to check whether a recordset is empty using the BOF and EOF properties (see code below).  I know this code works as I've used it previously in other instances.  However, for some reason (while testing) when I deleted the last record in my subform the properties are both FALSE.  As I understand it, this means that there are records remaining.  However once the code has run, there are no records in the subform and the query that the subform is based on is empty.  My thought process is that this is some sort of timing issue, but I would really appreciate your help to enlighten me and how to improve the code so it actually works as expected.

Something which makes me think it is a timing issue is that when I reload the form which includes the subform, both the property states are now TRUE...strange.  See the code below:

```
Private Sub supp_del_Click()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim Title As String
    Dim dbrec As Recordset
    Dim checkDel As Variant
    Dim idCheck As Integer

    'Run the Error handler when an error occurs.'
On Error GoTo Errhandler

    Set dbrec = Me.supp_subform.Form.Recordset

    'delete record'
    'check existing selected record'
    If Not (dbrec.EOF And dbrec.BOF) Then
        'set msgbox text'
        Msg =   "Are you sure you want to delete this supplier?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "ID: " & dbrec.Fields("supp_ID") & vbCrLf & _
                "Name: " & dbrec.Fields("supp_name") & vbCrLf & _
                "Map: " & dbrec.Fields("supp_map") & vbCrLf & _
                "Tax code: " & dbrec.Fields("tax_code") & vbCrLf & _
                "Department: " & dbrec.Fields("Department")
        Title = "Point of no return"

        result = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo, Title)

        'confirm delete'
        If result = vbYes Then
            idCheck = dbrec.Fields("supp_id")
            'delete now'
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM suppliers " & _
                                " WHERE supp_ID=" & idCheck

            If DLookup("[supp_ID]", "[suppliers]", "supp_id=" & idCheck) Then
                'set msgbox text'
                Msg = "Cannot delete as the supplier has an invoice allocated to them."
                Title = "Cannot delete"
                result = MsgBox(Msg, vbOK, Title)
            Else
                'refresh data in list'
                dbrec.Requery
                'enable/disable buttons depending on if form list is empty'
                If Not (dbrec.EOF And dbrec.BOF) Then
                    Me.supp_subform.Enabled = True
                    Me.Supp_edit.Enabled = True
                    Me.supp_del.Enabled = True
                Else
                    Me.supp_subform.Enabled = False
                    Me.Supp_edit.Enabled = False
                    Me.supp_del.Enabled = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub
Errhandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case 3021 ' error '3021 'no current record - it think's there aren't any records'
            'select all records in suppliers'
            sqlstr = "SELECT supp_ID, supp_name, tax_code, supp_map, Department FROM suppliers;"
            Set dbrec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlstr)
            'select first record and allocate to form fields'
            dbrec.MoveFirst
            'set msgbox text'
            Msg =   "Are you sure you want to delete this supplier?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    "ID: " & dbrec.Fields(0) & vbCrLf & _
                    "Name: " & dbrec.Fields(1) & vbCrLf & _
                    "Map: " & dbrec.Fields(3) & vbCrLf & _
                    "Tax code: " & dbrec.Fields(2) & vbCrLf & _
                    "Department: " & dbrec.Fields(4)
            Title = "Point of no return"

            result = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo, Title)
            'confirm delete'
            If result = vbYes Then
                idCheck = dbrec.Fields(0)
                'delete now'
                CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM suppliers " & _
                                    " WHERE supp_ID=" & idCheck
                If DLookup("[supp_ID]", "[suppliers]", "supp_id=" & idCheck) Then
                    'set msgbox text'
                    Msg = "Cannot delete as the supplier has an invoice allocated to them."
                    Title = "Cannot delete"
                    result = MsgBox(Msg, vbOK, Title)
                Else
                    'refresh data in list'
                    Set dbrec = Me.supp_subform.Form.Recordset
                    dbrec.Requery
                    If Not (dbrec.EOF And dbrec.BOF) Then
                        Me.supp_subform.Enabled = True
                        Me.Supp_edit.Enabled = True
                        Me.supp_del.Enabled = True
                    Else
                        Me.supp_subform.Enabled = False
                        Me.Supp_edit.Enabled = False
                        Me.supp_del.Enabled = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Case Else 'all other errors'
            Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
                    & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Err.Description
            MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You're requerying the form but you should be requerying the recordset. Change the line `Me.supp_subform.Form.Requery` to `dbrec.Requery`.

Comment: @user3728595 I changed it as you said and have updated the code above.  Strangely now the BOF and EOF properties continually say true, even if there are records...

I have an add sub as well with similar (same) coding for this and it seems to work.  I checked out the "absolutePosition" of the recordset which if there's a record should indicate 0 for 1 record and it seems to be fine (-1 for zero records).  I guess I could use this as a replacement for my test but still not sure why this isn't working correctly.

Comment: I have checked again and you are right about BOF/EOF, despite the fact that [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821155.aspx) says "If both the BOF and EOF property settings of the Recordset object are True after you use the Requery method, the query didn't return any records and the Recordset contains no data." So much for design behaviour.

Comment: Instead of your `CurrentDb.Execute` method above you could use the following code: `dbrec.Delete` | `dbrec.MoveFirst` | `If dbrec.EOF Then...`

Comment: @user3728595 not sure I quite follow...how would I incorporate the dbrec.delete code etc instead of currentDb.Execute?

Comment: I cannot format the code as I wish in a comment, so I'll try posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Within the code posted in your question, remove the line starting

```
CurrentDb.Execute ...
```

and replace with:

```
dbrec.Delete ' Delete the current record from the recordset
```

Remove the line:

```
dbrec.Requery
```

and replace with:

```
dbrec.MoveFirst ' Move to the top of the recordset for testing
If Not dbrec.EOF Then ... ' Recordset contains records
```